# How to append values to an Excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, append

I know this question is very old but i am not finding any answer to this.

How to append values into existing excel file and to a particular column.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
string sql = null;

MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=filelocation;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

MyConnection.Open();
myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;

sql = "Insert into ["+ sheetname +"$] (Result) values ("+ result +")";
myCommand.CommandText = sql;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
MyConnection.Close();
```

I even tried different method like opening Excel through C# and append, nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to use `OLEDB` [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5123/Opening-and-Navigating-Excel-with-C) is a good article how to operate excel files by using early binding.

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout below links

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-Data-to-Excel-Sheet-using-ADO.Net-and-C.aspx 
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-and-Import-Excel-Sheet-using-ADO.Net-and-C.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using OLEDB to work with excel files has it's problems and shortcomings. It is better to use a third-party library. I recomment [CSharpJExcel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/) for Excel 97-2003 (xls) files or [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for Excel 2007 (xlsx) files. You don't need to even have Microsoft Excel installed.